# Find all words that not contain specefic letter in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex

How to find all words in a string that not contain letter `i` using regex. For example the string is

```
This is my first regex example
```

output should be

```
my
regex
example
```

EDIT: I tried the blow regex, but not working

```
"\\b\\w*[^i]\\w*\\b"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you need regex for this? (split and search would be easier)

Comment: @Crazy, Updated my question

Comment: How did you try this regex? Add the Java code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

`\b[^i\s]+\b`

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - [a word-boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - returns a 0 length match between a word and a non-word character
- `[^i\s]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is neither `i` nor a white-space character
- `\b` - a word boundary

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I10Cnn/1/)

[Click for JAVA code](https://regex101.com/r/I10Cnn/1/codegen?language=java)

Comment: Great, could you explain you regex please ?

Comment: Very nice answer +1. Not sure if OP wants to match digits or underscore though, in that case they can use `\b[^i\W\d_]+\b`

Comment: @FSm added the explanation.

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks for improving it :)

Answer (score 1):

Regex will be like:

```
(?i)\\b[a-hj-z]+\\b
```

We need to find words and for that we use word boundary `\b` in the end and start of expression. Part between `\b` is class that matches one symbol that contains letter from `a-h` and from `j-z`, and we didn't use `i` letter in this range so result of matching will be like you needed. For matching words and not only one symbol in this range we use + that tells that class need to be one or more times repeated.
`(?i)` in start of expression is flag that tells to interpret all letters as case insensitive.

P.S. simple regex tutorial already included in javadoc of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) java class